# MySQL Para un rango de números

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy elaborando una base de datos conectado a un sistema CRUD en PHP y MySQL y ya llevo mas de una semana tratando de encontrar la solución mas optima para la siguiente tarea.

El sistema CRUD tiene 2 campos, Identificación y Rango. La idea es que cuando se digite la identificación automáticamente el campo de rango se ponga el valor asignado según una base de datos previamente cargada. Dependiendo del método, ya tengo la forma en que me va a rellenar automáticamente el campo rango. En algunos momentos pueden haber hasta 20 personas introduciendo datos.

**Primera opción**

Mi base de datos esta de esta forma (uso excel para ilustrar mejor):

[image: DB primera opción]

`select * from dbrango where IDENTIFICACION_INICIAL = 70000017`

Resultado: 6

Cada identificación tiene un rango asociado, el problema esta en que de esta forma tengo que ponerle el rango a los números del 70000000 al 90000000 y quedaría una tabla con hasta 20 millones de filas y aunque tengo herramientas para ponerle el rango a 20 millones de registros y algo me dice que esto no es tan viable u optimo.

**Segunda opción**

Mi base de datos esta de esta forma (uso excel para ilustrar mejor):

[image: DB segunda opción]

Esta es la forma que mas me convence, pero me da error en sistaxis, en el código PHP puedo realizar una consulta que si por ejemplo el usuario digita 70003231, entonces:

`select * from dbrango where IDENTIFICACION_INICIAL >= 70003231 and IDENTIFICACION_FINAL <= 70003231`

Debería salir: 17

Si tengo que asignar rango del 70000000 al 90000000 obviamente la tabla quedaría con menos registros, pasaría de 20 millones a 100000, puesto que ya no asignaría el rango 1 por identificación si no por un rango de identificación (del 70000000 al 700000199 rango 1).

¿Cuál creen uds que esta la mejor opción de las propuestas para realizar esto?

¿Alguna sugerencia para realizar esta tarea?

Tengo opción para migrar a SQLServer si se requiere o utilizar librerías externas.

Todas las sugerencia o comentarios son bien recibidos.

**Muchas gracias de antemano.**

Comment: Tus 2 ejemplos son incongruentes en el primer caso 70000003 tiene rango 3 y en el segundo 2. Para mi claramente la segunda opción es mejor, no obstante si la siempre es lo mismo, es decir comienza en 70000000 y cada rango son 200 números puede ser mejor usar una fórmula  que crear una tabla

Comment: ¿Puedes crear esas tablas en https://dbfiddle.uk/ER_9PaV- para poder ayudarte? ¿Qué error de sintaxis obtienes con la segunda opción?

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos por responder. Ya una respuesta me ayudo con mi duda.

Answer (score 0):

Sugerencia, así no mas, solo lo dejo por si a nadie se le paso por la cabeza usar matematicas en lugar de base de datos registros extensos y perdida de milisegundos, latencias etc.

```js
// Rango inicial 70000000
function calcula(obj){

let valor=obj.value;
let div_resultado=document.querySelector("#este_es_el_rango");

//Para que no se vea mal el resultado no muestro rango si el numero es menor a la base
if((parseInt(valor)-70000000)<=0){div_resultado.innerHTML=0; return;}

// tomamos el numero le restamos la base y dividimos por 200 que es el rango, luego elevamos el resultado dandonos el rango buscado
valor=Math.ceil((parseInt(valor)-70000000)/200);

div_resultado.innerHTML=valor;
}


// esto es para mostrar al cargar el ejemplo
const el = document.querySelector("#rango");
calcula(el);
```

```html
Escribe el numero, debe ser mayor a 70000000<br>
<input id="rango" value="70003231" onkeyup="calcula(this)"><br><br>
Rango:
<div id="este_es_el_rango">0</div>
```

muchas veces la respuesta en simplificar las cosas y no al contrario

NOTA: lo hice en Javascript pero lo puedes pasar a php, solo lo hice asi para que puedas usarlo en vivo y ver como cambia el rango al cambiar la cifra

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, voy a realizar pruebas con el ejemplo que dejaste. Ya con con tu respuesta se por donde agarrar y modificar según mis necesidades.